# Best approaches to UPDATE the data in tables - Teradata

Tags: performance, teradata

I am new to `Teradata` & fortunately got a chance to work on both `DDL-DML` statements.

One thing I observed is Teradata is very slow when time comes to `UPDATE` the data in a table having large number of records.

The simplest way I found on the `Google` to perform this update is to write an `INSERT-SELECT` statement with a `CASE` on column holding values to be update with new values.

But what when this situation arrives in `Data Warehouse` environment, when we need to update multiple columns from a table holding millions of rows ?
Which would be the best approach to follow ?

`INSERT-SELECT` only OR `MERGE-UPDATE` OR `MLOAD` ?

Not sure if any of the above approach is not used for this `UPDATE` operation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If no index can be used an Update requires a Full Table Scan, but is usually quite fast (only updating the Primary Index or Partitioning columns is slow, but bad practice anyway). Additionally a huge Update might result in a huge Transient Jornal. What's the number of rows in your table and the percentage of updated rows? And how is your Update coded?

Comment: @Dnoeth At present we are having 382,851,001 # of rows in fact table. But this is weekly-monthly incremental. So right now we are ok with INSERT-SELECT approach. But soon this is going to be fail in our case due to space constraint. FYI, we have more than one column user a PI & table is a mutliset. Usually we need an update on columns which are not PI.

Comment: Any Secondary/Join indices? MERGE is usually better than UPDATE (might avoid spooling). How is your Update coded? A huge Select or a source table?

Comment: @dnoeth, no secondary indices used in table. The update is also simple one with join. For ex:- update fact from fact, dim set col1 = col2 where ...

Answer (score 0):

At enterprise level, we expect volumes to be huge and updates are often part of some scheduled jobs/scripts.

With huge volume of data, Updates comes as a costly operation that involve risk of blocking table for some time in case the update fails (due to fallback journal). Although scripts are tested well, and failures seldom happen in production environments, it's always better to have data that needs to be updated loaded to a temporary table in required form and inserted back to same table after deleting matching records to maintain  SCD-1 (Where we don't maintain history).

Comment: Can MLOAD utility be used for this purpose ? If yes, does it gives better performance ?

Comment: As we are talking about updates on a table, other load and export utilities move out of picture (fast load, fastexport & BTEQ: not suitable for bulk). What remains is either MLoad or TPump. Mload beats TPump in performance unless and until updates happen over a very small volume of records. When this happens TPump performance may approach that of Mload. Mload operates on Block level while TPump on row level.